# Did Dropbox 3.8.5 break multiple instances?

Tags: automator, dropbox

For a while, I've been running two Dropbox accounts, a personal and a work account, and it's been great.  The method that I'm using is with an Automator workflow that fires up on boot.  All that's in there, is the standard method found on the web for this...

```
bash
HOME=$HOME/Dropbox-second /Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/Dropbox &
```

...that launches the second account.  Suddenly, I noticed that there was an update to 3.8.5, and now the first instance launches and syncs fine, but the second instance launches then sits forever with spinning arrows, and the status "Starting".  It's not just on one machine, it's on all of them.  Also, if I quit both instances, and launch the second (via the Automator script), it launches and syncs fine.  If I then double-click on the Dropbox app, to launch the first instance, now that is the one that just spins, saying, "Starting".

Anyone else had this?  Anyone found a work-around?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've experience the same issue since the update.

Comment: According to the FAQ for the software "Dropbox Encore", this issue was introduced with 3.8.5, and still exists.  They were apparently able to find a workaround for users of 10.10.4+.  Source: http://www.joyofmacs.com/software/dropboxencore/#EncoreStalls